# Does DDL for creating Oracle temporary tables commit transaction?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

How can I create a temporary table in Oracle db (CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE) without the DDL to commit the transaction?

I want the same behavour like on MySQL. From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

> CREATE TABLE does not automatically commit the current active
>   transaction if you use the TEMPORARY keyword.

Comment: Yes, **every** DDL in Oracle implicitly commits. Note that in Oracle you typically create a (global) temporary only *once*. You don't create them "on the fly".

Comment: You should not need to create objects on the fly, tables (including temporary ones) should only be created under controlled conditions - typically when your application is installed or upgraded. It isn't common to really need a temporary table in Oracle, they aren't used in the same way as other databases. If you describe what you're using it for we might be able to suggest a suitable approach.

Comment: Never mix DML and DDL - this is rule if thumb for Oracle. Aplying of one database's patterns on other database is not recommended. You should usually use a cursor or some complex type in Oracle, where you use temporary table in MySQL/MSSQL. In Oracle when you need a temporary table, then probably there is something wrong with your design.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, DDL commits your transaction.

In addtion to Franek's answer, I want to point out that you should not need to create a *global temporary table* on the fly as all data within such a table is private to the session that inserted it.

So, if you create the global temporary table *once*, your session can safely use this table without fear of interfering with other sessions, and the ddl-commit issue becomes non-relevant.

Comment: I would be careful with statement that "you should not need to create a global temporary table on the fly" because sometimes there is need to recreate temporary table, e.g. when it is used for ETL and such ETL can be redefined at runtime. In my opinion this is not rarely used in that way...

Comment: I thought I had been careful. I have written *should*, not *must*.

Answer (score 1):

You can CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE in new transaction by using PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION to avoid autocommit in your current transaction like below:

```
    create or replace
      PROCEDURE create_gtt IS
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      BEGIN
      execute immediate 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE gtt_table ( '||
     ' column1  NUMBER, ' ||
     ' ) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS';
    END;
```

In such scenario, calling create_gtt will not commit your insert:

```
    CREATE TABLE test_table (test_value VARCHAR2(25));

    begin
        insert into test_table(test_value) values ('TEST');
        create_gtt;
    end;
```